# Conditional probability with random bit rewrites

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

When you turn on a computer, a certain bit (0/1) in its memory is initialized to the value 0.

Suppose that starting from when you turn on your computer the bit is rewritten at random instants, on average λ times per millisecond, and each rewrite results in a 1 independently with probability 
(or a 0 is written with probability (1 − ) when a rewrite occurs). What is the probability that after t milliseconds the bit stores the value 0?

I want to condition on whether or not a rewrite has occurred before t milliseconds, but I'm not sure how to obtain the answer. I also think to use binomial properties.

Comment: Does that mean you care only about whether $1$ was written *at some point*, or could it go from $1$ back to $0$?

Comment: it can go back from 1 to 0

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1. What is the probability the bit has never been rewritten by time $t$?
2. What is the probability the bit has been rewritten by time $t$ at least once?
3. Given it has been rewritten, what is the probability that the latest rewrite was a $0$?
4. How would you combine (1), (2) and (3) to find the probability the bit is $0$ at time $t$?

Comment: I am unsure of #1 (and thus #4). However, I know that #2 is (1 minus the probability in #1). #3 is (1-p) I believe.

Comment: @theta You can use either the exponential distribution or the Possion distribution to answer (1).  It should be a decreasing function of both $\lambda$ and $t$ as both a higher rate and a longer time make it more likely that the bit will be rewritten

Comment: There is a bit of assumption for answering $(1)$, but I think it's safe to say the Poisson distribution is what's intended here.

Comment: Do I do P(0) = P(0 | no rewrites)*P(no rewrites) + P(0 | at least 1 rewrite)P(at least one rewrite)?

Comment: @theta Yes precisely that

Comment: @Fimpellizieri The assumption is that "the bit is rewritten at random instants, on average $\lambda$ times per millisecond" suggests a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$.  Using a Poisson distribution for the number of rewrites or an exponential distribution for the time of the first rewrite will give the same answer for (1) of $e^{-\lambda t}$